# What to use instead of ensure_index() in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

MongoDB's (and pymongo's) `ensure_index` has been deprecated after version 3.0. What should I use if I only want to drop an index in a collection if it exists?

pymongo's documentation claims that `drop_index` *"Can be used on non-existant collections or collections with no indexes"*, but there is an `OperationFailure` raised if I try to drop a non-existent index from a collection. Before version 3.0, I could use `ensure_index` to see if an index exists before doing anything, what should I be doing now?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are two ways:

1. A try/except statement in Python with the except statement being `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure`, or, even better for my case:
2. `db.my_collection.drop_indexes()` works on collections withouts indexes.